# Left oriented viewPageer in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

How can I create a `left-oriented ViewPager`?

- **Last element**: should be on the left side
- **First element**: should be on the right side.

List of items, which `ViewPager` should show increase dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Just page your viewpager to the last element while initing a activity. And add new elemetns to start